# Odoo see only one db to login, but there are more dbs for same odoo user

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I installed odoo 10 on CentOS 7. when I run odoo command odoo start or ./usr/bin/odoo 
open browser, see only one db to login to, but there are many dbs for this odoo user.

Answer (score 0):

ip_addresss:port/web/database/manager. not show all dbs for me.

Odoo config file not have dbfilter but I add dbfilter when run odoo like:

./usr/bin/odoo  --db-filter '.*'

odoo run and show all databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify *db_filter* in your configuration file.
Filter is in REGEXP format, so the expression bellow list all database granted for your *db_user*

```
db_user = your_db_user
db_filter = .*
```